# Why do I know the user ID and message ID for getting email messages from the gmail API?

Tags: angular, google-api, gmail-api

I have an Angular 6 application. I am attempting to retrieve my email messages from my gmail account by connect to Google’s API.

This link here explains how:

> https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#examples

It says to call this endpoint with your userId and message id:

> https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/userId/messages/id

The problem is, I have no idea what my userId or message id are. How do I figure that out?

PS - I’m not using the gapi client library or any library because I’m trying to program the application to be able to hit any API endpoint, not just Google’s.

Comment: just a question: why would gapi client hinder you for hitting other endpoints?

Comment: Are you suggesting that gapi can be used to hit OneDrive, for example? Doesn't the g in gapi stand for Google?

Comment: No, I was not suggesting to use it for something it is not inteded for. Maybe just a misunderstanding, to me it just sounded like that if you use it, you can't hit any other endpoints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the docs you linked to...

```
  /**
   * Get Message with given ID.
   *
   * @param service Authorized Gmail API instance.
   * @param userId User's email address. The special value "me"
   * can be used to indicate the authenticated user.
   * @param messageId ID of Message to retrieve.
   * @return Message Retrieved Message.
   * @throws IOException
   */
```

> userId: User's email address. The special value "me" can be used to indicate the authenticated user.

I imagine you'd find the message id by inspecting an individual message object with the API. If you don't know any message ID's, logically you won't be able to inspect an individual message, you'd need to grab all the messages and then pick one.

Comment: Thanks John for pointing that out. Should have been obvious to me, but I missed it. As for the message ID, I managed to get the list of messages in postman and despite a common misconception on the internet, the IDs are NOT the one you see in the url when you view your messages in gmail.